# Order of output data in d3.sort() - ascending vs descending

Tags: javascript, sorting, d3.js

I tried running the following code:

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
<script>

console.log([10,2,3,7].sort(d3.ascending));  // 1
console.log([10,2,3,7].sort(d3.descending));  // 2

console.log([10,NaN,2,3,7].sort(d3.ascending));  // 3
console.log([10,NaN,2,3,7].sort(d3.descending));  // 4

console.log([10,undefined,2,NaN,3,7].sort(d3.ascending)); // 5
console.log([10,undefined,2,NaN,3,7].sort(d3.descending));  // 6
</script>
```

And the discrepancies in output between the ascending and descending order sorting has me stumped.

```
CONSOLE OUTPUT:
[Log] [2, 3, 7, 10] 
[Log] [10, 7, 3, 2] 
**[Log] [2, 3, 7, 10, NaN]**
**[Log] [10, NaN, 7, 3, 2]**
[Log] [2, 7, 10, NaN, 3, undefined]
[Log] [10, 7, 2, NaN, 3, undefined]
```

The observable D3 tutorials don't seem to address this. In fact, there appears to some other points there (regarding d3.count() being able to count strings) which also proved to be wrong when I ran the code. Therefore, I could not rely on https://observablehq.com/@d3/

Does anyone know if the output is expected or why the order is as shown in the output?

Comment: what result do you expect for `null` and `undefined` values?

Comment: I expected the sort would still consider the NaN and undefined values and do something with it. But, I expect some consistency between ascending and descending orders of sort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a D3 issue, but a javascript one.

If you look at the source code, the only thing [`ascending`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/main/src/ascending.js) does differently from a basic comparison (i.e., `(a, b) => a - b`) is testing for `null` before comparing the numbers:

```
function ascending(a, b) {
    return a == null || b == null ? NaN : a < b ? -1 : a > b ? 1 : a >= b ? 0 : NaN;
}
```

`descending` is pretty much the same thing, but with `a` and `b` swapped.

Now back to your question. First of all, the output you described for the third `console.log()` is incorrect, `NaN` is never at the last position:

```js
function descending(a, b) {
  return a == null || b == null ? NaN : b < a ? -1 : b > a ? 1 : b >= a ? 0 : NaN;
}

function ascending(a, b) {
  return a == null || b == null ? NaN : a < b ? -1 : a > b ? 1 : a >= b ? 0 : NaN;
}

console.log([10, NaN, 2, 3, 7].sort(ascending));
console.log([10, NaN, 2, 3, 7].sort(descending));
```

What's happening here is that any comparison with `NaN` will return `false`:

```js
console.log(NaN > 42);
console.log(NaN < 42);
console.log(NaN === 42);
```

Therefore, the D3 results are expected (and also note that there's no discrepancy between `d3.ascending` and `d3.descending`). Actually, you get the same results with plain JavaScript:

```js
console.log([10, NaN, 2, 3, 7].sort((a, b) => a - b)); 
console.log([10, NaN, 2, 3, 7].sort((a, b) => b - a));
```

Finally, it's worth mentioning that since the letter `N` comes after all the numbers, the JavaScript `sort` without the comparing function will put the `NaN`s at the end (and `"10"` before `"2"`, obviously):

```js
console.log([10, NaN, 2, 3, 7].sort());
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for taking the time to provide some clarity. I now understand that d3.ascending and d3.descending don't really play a role here. The output is the same as it would be with plain Javascript sort. However, I don't understand what you mean by this - " the output you described for the third console.log() is incorrect, NaN is never at the last position". I ran the code snippet I posted as well as the plain Javascript code in the last 2 code snippets included in your answer and I see that NaN is in the last position. Can you please explain?

Comment: @aashima Sort depends on the implementation, you're probably using Safari. Try Chrome or Firefox, you'll see the difference.

Comment: Wow, you're right! I see a different result on Chrome. Thank you, this helped so much!

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, the function `sort()` handles every non-numeric values like `NaN` and `undefined`. In JavaScript `NaN` is a special value and is not equal to any other value, including itself, that's why when you try to sort an array that contains `NaN`, it apears last in the ascending order. `undefined` it's a missing value and is considered less than any other value, that's why `undefined` appears last in both the ascending and descending order. This behavioris not specific to D3, it's just the JavaScript language.

Comment: NaN appears last in the ascending order, so why then does it appear second in the descending order?
`**[Log] [2, 3, 7, 10, NaN]**`
`**[Log] [10, NaN, 7, 3, 2]**`